# Google Compute E2 Increased CPU Usage Over Time

Tags: cpu-usage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a known issue for E2 CPU's regarding unexpected increase in CPU usage over time? I have replicated this multiple times already, and even for idle VM's. This is very critical, it is slowly increasing CPU usage over several weeks!

I recently switched from N1 to E2-small, and over time E2 is increasing its CPU usage. While my N1 VM's, this is not happening. I have personally used N1 for several years already.

Example 1: 2 E2 Vm's that are idle (no users yet):

[image: two-e2s]

The workaround is to reboot the server, however it will slowly creep up again over the weeks.

Example 2: Haproxy server using E2 CPU. Then restarted:

[image: proxy-e2]

And last example which is more definitive, I made a new N1 vm that is idle and compared it with a restarted E2-small instance that is also idle:

[image: e2vn1]

The E2-small corresponds to the violet line (it has been restarted), and the same day a new N1 (g1-small) has been created. Both are idle VM's, and you can see that E2 is slowly creeping up again, while N1 is retaining its cpu usage (expected behavior).

I have witnessed this E2 issue on more than 6 VM's already. All examples here are running on Debian 10.

Does anybody have any idea? Thank you.

[Update 2021-02-06] top results:

[image: top]

Comment: Hey Manny, I assume it's using Linux, can you look at top or htop, Seems like there is a process taking up the CPU.

Comment: @MarkScheck I have added the top results. Can it be that google_os+ is the culprit?

Comment: I would also look at sar, iostat, vmstat and see if there are any patterns.